# Como usar JQuery Sortable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sortable

tenho [esse código](http://jsfiddle.net/jedarc/9cvna8x8/) onde estou usando o `sortable` do JQuery. Mas estou com problemas, pois gostaria que cada item fosse movimentado apenas pelo `ico`, mas o atual código permite arrastar cada item a partir de qualquer lugar dele.
Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa referenciar o objeto responsável pela chamada do sortable, utilize o atributo `handle` do plugin.

```
$("#conteudo").sortable({handle: ".ico"});
```

Onde `.ico` é o seletor do seu objeto.

Comment: vlw fera, funcionou perfeitamente aqui!